# addObjects adds only last object to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I am making an Schedule class and trying to output all events in a loop in a ViewController. I have created an Event class and Schedule class. I am looping thorough NSMutableArray to get the text all of all the events. My problem is that when I am in the **addNewEvent** method in Schedule.m file I overwrite my NSMutable array with the last object I am adding through **addObject**. My goal is to add all the event objects one by one into the array and display their text. It would also be nice if I could set separate IDs for the event objects. I understand that I probably need to loop through something in the **addNewEvent** method when I am adding objects to the mutable array, but I don't know through what. I also thought that maybe I am initializing the NSMutableArray (which is a property of the Schedule class) in the wrong place, but it gives an error if I move the initializer anywhere else.

Could you please help me solve this problem. Any help will be much appreciated!

My Code is below. I have two classes (Event & Schedule) and a ViewController file.

Event.h:

```
@interface Event : NSObject

@property int eventId;

@property NSString * eventTitle;

@property NSString * eventDescription;

@property NSDate * eventDate;

-(void) logEvent;

-(NSString*) getEventText;

@end
```

Event.m:

```
#import "Event.h"

@implementation Event

-(NSString*) getEventText {

    NSString * eventText1 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"\n\nEvent ID: %d.\n", _eventId];

    NSString * eventText2 = [eventText1 stringByAppendingFormat: @"Title: %@.\n", _eventTitle];

    NSString * eventText3 = [eventText2 stringByAppendingFormat:@"Description: %@.\n", _eventDescription];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterFullStyle;
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;

    NSString * eventText = [eventText3 stringByAppendingFormat:@"Date: %@.\n\n", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:_eventDate]];

    return eventText;
}

@end
```

Schedule.h:

```
@interface Schedule : NSObject

@property int idIndex;

@property NSMutableArray * scheduledEvents;

-(NSString*) getAllEventText;

-(void)addNewEventWithTitle:(NSString *)Title Description:(NSString *)Description andDate:(NSDate *)Date;

@end
```

Schedule.m:

```
#import "Schedule.h"
#import "Event.h"

@implementation Schedule

-(void)addNewEventWithTitle:(NSString *)Title Description:(NSString *)Description andDate:(NSDate *)Date {

    Event * event = [[Event alloc] init];

    _idIndex = 1;

    [event setEventTitle:Title];
    [event setEventDescription:Description];
    [event setEventDate:Date];
    [event setEventId:_idIndex];

    NSLog(@"%@", [event getEventText]);

    _scheduledEvents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [_scheduledEvents addObject: event];

    NSLog(@"%lu", [_scheduledEvents count]);

}

-(NSString*) getAllEventText {

    NSString * allEventText;

    // loop through NSMutableArray calling each Event's getEventText method using a for loop

    for (int i=0; i<[_scheduledEvents count]; i++) {

        allEventText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Event %d: %@\n", i+1, [_scheduledEvents[i] getEventText] ];

        NSLog(@"%@", [_scheduledEvents[i] getEventText]);

    }

    // return concatenated string

    return allEventText;

}

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Schedule * mySchedule = [[Schedule alloc] init];

    [mySchedule addNewEventWithTitle:@"My Birthday" Description:@"My most cherished birthday" andDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:484830000]];

    [mySchedule addNewEventWithTitle:@"Meeting with the Client" Description:@"My most important meeting" andDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:481302000]];

    [mySchedule addNewEventWithTitle:@"Appointment with Family Doctor" Description:@"My most urgent appointment" andDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:480270000]];

    [_outputTextView setText:[mySchedule getAllEventText]];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are re-initializing scheduledEvents everytime `addNewEventWithTitle:Description:andDate` is called.

You have to move `_scheduledEvents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` in your viewDidLoad method.

Comment: It does not allow me to do this. When I do this, Xcode says: "use of undeclared identifier '_scheduledEvents'."

Comment: Ok then move that code to the init method inside Schedule.m file

Comment: You mean do something like this:                                                                    - (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
  _scheduledEvents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}? When I do this, it still outputs only the last object to my ViewController view.

Comment: Yes that's correct. Now make sure you removed _scheduledEvents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; inside addNewEventWithTitle:Description:andDate

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
-(void)addNewEventWithTitle:(NSString *)Title Description:(NSString *)Description andDate:(NSDate *)Date {
    // ...
    _scheduledEvents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // <--
    // ...
}
```

By definition, if `_scheduledEvents` already has any value (an existing array), that line destroys that value and replaces it with a new empty array. So the result of running your `addNewEvent...` method will *always* be that `_scheduledEvents` ends up consisting of just this one event.

Comment: Yes, I understand that there is a problem with where I put the initializer for the array. If I remove the line you are pointing to, nothing will be outputted to my ViewController view. With the line where it is now, the last object added is outputted.

Comment: And I just explained that. After all, if you don't put an empty NSMutableArray into `_scheduledEvents` at _some_ point, there won't be one, and so there's nothing to add anything to and nothing happens. But _you_ are doing it _every time this method is called_, and so you always destroy any existing array. Try to do some thinking here. There is a very obvious happy medium between _never_ creating the array and creating the array _every_ time: create the NSMutableArray _just once_!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: the problem was in the **getAllEventText** method.

The **allEventText** string was constantly replacing its own content in the for loop in the method previously.

I had to change the **NSString** to **NSMutableString** and use the **append** method to add to the existing string, and not replace its content.

So I changed the method as follows and it works now:

```
-(NSString*) getAllEventText {

NSMutableString* allEventText = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:150];

// loop through NSMutableArray calling each Event's getEventText method using a for loop

for (int i=0; i<[_scheduledEvents count]; i++) {

    [allEventText appendFormat:@"Event %d: %@\n", i+1, [_scheduledEvents[i] getEventText]];

    NSLog(@"%@", [_scheduledEvents[i] getEventText]);

}

// return concatenated string

return allEventText;

}
```

Also big thanks to metronic and matt for suggesting that I need to move the MSMutableArray initializer away from the **addNewEvent** method!!